# Remove element in list with bool flag with List Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Wondering if there would be a neat way to use `List Comprehension` to accomplish removing an element from a list based on a bool.

## example

```
test_list = [
     "apple",
     "orange",
     "grape",
     "lemon"
]
apple = True
    if apple:
        test_list.remove("apple")

print(test_list)
```

## expected output

```
['orange', 'grape', 'lemon']
```

I know I could so something like:

```
test_list = [x for x in test_list if "apple" not in x]
```

But wondering if I could use a bool flag to do this instead of a string as I only want to to run if the bool is `True`.

Comment: One thing to be careful of is how each approach handles repeated elements - I could be wrong, but I think if `apple` appears multiple times, `list.remove("apple")` will only remove the first, while the filter would remove all of them.

Can you elaborate on what you mean by a bool flag?

Comment: Note: `if "apple" not in x` in your own suggestion is definitely incorrect, since `x` is a single element, not a list.

Comment: @EdwardPeters Thanks for the help! Yeah, I could have put more thought into the question. Basically I have a function with a bool arg, that I want to determine to either remove a specific element or leave the list as it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test_list = [x for x in test_list if not (apple and x == "apple")]
```

Results:

```
>>> apple = True
>>> [x for x in test_list if not (apple and x == "apple")]
['orange', 'grape', 'lemon']

>>> apple = False
>>> [x for x in test_list if not (apple and x == "apple")]
['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'lemon']
```

---

Note: Going by the initial example, removing one element from a list depending on a flag, I would stick to that example, which is very clear what it does:

```
if apple:
    test_list.remove("apple")
```

My list comprehension condition takes more effort to understand. Clarity beats conciseness and (premature) optimisation. There is no good reason with your example to use a list comprehension.

Also: my list comprehension is *not* precisely equivalent as the `if - .remove(...)` part, as pointed out by Edward Peters. The list comprehension will remove all elements that are `"apple"` (if `apple is True`), while the `if - .remove()` variant will only remove the first occurrence of `"apple"`, and leave any remaining `"apple"` elements in the list.

Should you desire the first behaviour, I'd be inclined to use:

```
if apple:
    test_list = [item for item in test_list if item != "apple"]
```

which is still much clearer than the list comprehension with the double condition, while still using the practicality of a list comprehension to filter a list.

Comment: This is great! Do you know because we are looping through the list here, it isn't as optimized has using something like `remove` or `pop`? Just thinking if while more concise it might be better to use a if statement?

Comment: Ok thanks! I appreciate the effort to help, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

We can create a boolean list and use a list comprehension to get the `test_list` without the `apple` item inside:

```
test_list = [
     "apple",
     "orange",
     "grape",
     "lemon"
]

test_list_bool=[True if x=='apple' else False for x in test_list]

test_list=[test_list[i] for i in range(len(test_list)) if not test_list_bool[i]]
```

**Output**

```py
>>> test_list
>>> ['orange', 'grape', 'lemon']
```

Comment: This misses the boolean flag that the OP is asking about. See the initial example in the question.

Comment: This also overcomplicates things, and will leave anyone reading the code wondering why it is coded this way, instead of a simple direct comparison in a single list comprehension.

Comment: It's imortant to know different ways/codes of doing a same action

Comment: Yes, but overcomplicating things sets a bad example. Now, if this were NumPy and you used indexing with a boolean array, that would make sense. But that's not this.